# C# 7.0 case pattern matching on generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, switch-statement, c#-7.0

Is there a reason for not being able to handle a generic variable by the type pattern? Please consider the code:

```
public static int CompareValues<T>(T left, T right)
{
  switch (left)
  {
    case IComparable<T> comparableDif:
      return comparableDif.CompareTo(right);
    case System.Numerics.Complex c:
      return c.Magnitude
        .CompareTo(((System.Numerics.Complex)(object)right).Magnitude);
    default:
      throw new ArgumentException("unsupported type");
  }
}
```

The first match on the IComparable interface is ok, but the second one does not compile. Why do I have to use this boxing workaround?

```
case object o when o is System.Numerics.Complex:
  return ((System.Numerics.Complex)o).Magnitude
    .CompareTo(((System.Numerics.Complex)(object)right).Magnitude);
```

Comment: You're switching on the parameter's value, not type.

Comment: For the same reason that the cast of `right` requires a boxing operation. There isn't really a cast from an arbitrary generic type T to Complex. It is possible to upcast to object (and thereby box a struct) and then attempt to unbox it as Complex. In the first case, `IComparable<T>` is an interface and it always possible to attempt to cast to an interface (and thereby box any struct)

Comment: @DavideVitali with C# 7 pattern matching, it can be both value and nature

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a consequence of how pattern matching in C# 7.0 is defined: for your type pattern to compile, a cast from `T` to `Complex` would have to exist, but it does not. The C# team realized it was a mistake to require this, so [this issue was fixed in C# 7.1](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-7.1/generics-pattern-match.md).

Comment: They moved proposal to https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-7.1/generics-pattern-match.md

Comment: @ГригорийШуренков Thanks, updated. (For the record, you could have proposed the edit to fix the link yourself.)